# .NET Core 3.1 Exception thrown in controller is logged before hitting middleware

Tags: c#, exception, logging, .net-core, middleware

I added an exception handling middleware to my `.net core 3.1 api`, but it doesn't behave as expected. I see plenty of log messages of unhandled exceptions.

I made a simple skeleton to reproduce it. I don't have logging configured, but the behavior is the same.

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.ConfigureExceptionHandler();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs

```
public static class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
{
    public static void ConfigureExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(applicationBuilder =>
        {
            applicationBuilder.Run(async httpContext => await ExceptionHandlerAsync(httpContext));
        });
    }

    private static async Task ExceptionHandlerAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        var message = contextFeature?.Error.Message ?? "Internal Server Error with no inner exception";

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(message);
    }
}
```

ExceptionController.cs

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]    
public class ExceptionController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("throw")]
    public IActionResult ThrowInController()
    {
        throw new Exception("Thrown in Controller");
    }
}
```

So if I debug it through, the flow is the following:

- hit http://localhost:53636/api/exception/throw
- breakpoint in `ExceptionController` is hit (on the `throw ...` command, at this point the console output (or log, if configured) is empty)
- exception is thrown in the `ExceptionController`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.` is written to console output (or logged)
- breakpoint in `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` is hit (on the `var contextFeature = ...;`, so the first line of the handler)
- exception handler logic is executed
- api response is returned

My issue is the intermediate "unhandled" exception message before the flow hits the middleware and the exception gets handled. In my real app, there's also logic to log as warning or info (and not as error) depending on the metadata of the exception. But currently every exception gets logged multiple times. First as Error (the unhandled exception) and secondly by the middleware with proper log level.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

**update**

I found a workaround. If I use `app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();` instead of `app.UseExceptionHandler(...)`, I no longer get the message about the unhandled exception.

ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs

```
public class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // handle exception, log it with the proper level, generate response, etc
        }
    }
}
```

I'd still be interested to know *why* though.

Comment: Place your custom ExceptionHandlerMiddleware after use.Authorization and before the use.Endpoints methods. The order of the methods is of the essence in middleware pipelines.

Comment: @SteliosGiakoumidis sadly it didn't help

Comment: where did you put your break point in controller?

Comment: @SteliosGiakoumidis I updated the question, maybe it's clearer this way

Comment: issue is still actual for ,net 5

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.5/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L106)

```
_logger.UnhandledException(edi.SourceException);
```

The `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` is logging exception as error **before** running your handler.

I solved this by disabling all logs from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`. If this solution is good enough for you just set this category logging level to `None`:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware": "None"
  }
}
```